# Javascript: Carousel slides out of the loop

Tags: javascript, carousel

I am currently building a carousel with vanilla JS and I've noticed that, unlike previous carousels I built before with jQuery, this one slides an extra slide out of the loop (which I defined with the `.length` property). The problem is happening in both directions.

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it? Here's a quick example:

```js
let currentSlide = 0
const holder = document.querySelector('.holder')
const totalSlides = holder.querySelectorAll('.holder-child')
const next = document.querySelector('.next')
const prev = document.querySelector('.prev')

const moveSlide = slide => {
  const leftPosition = -slide * 100 + 'vw'
  holder.style.left = leftPosition
}

const nextSlide = () => {
  currentSlide = currentSlide + 1
  moveSlide(currentSlide)
  if (currentSlide > totalSlides.length - 1) {
    currentSlide = 0
  }
}

const prevSlide = () => {
  currentSlide = currentSlide - 1
  moveSlide(currentSlide)
  if (currentSlide < 0) {
    currentSlide = totalSlides.length - 1
  }
}

next.addEventListener('click', () => {
  nextSlide()
})

prev.addEventListener('click', () => {
  prevSlide()
})
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.slideshow {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
}

.holder {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 500vw;
  transition: left 1s;
}

.holder-child {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
}

.speaker {
  padding: 0 8vw 0 8vw;
}

.controls {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<h2>Test</h2>
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="controls flex">
    <p class="prev pointer">prev</p>
    <p class="next pointer">next</p>
  </div>
  <div class=" holder flex">
    <div class="holder-child">
      <p>slide 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="holder-child">
      <p>slide 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5f8cbxdr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a minor logic issue caused by `moveSlide()` being called prior to the final calculation of `currentSlide` during your `prevSlide()` and `nextSlide()` methods.

Consider moving the call of `moveSlide()` to the end of your `prevSlide()` and `nextSlide()` functions. This will mean that when the edge cases occur (ie your `currentSlide` is at either end of the range of slides), the subsequent call to `moveSlide()` will cause the slides to be positioned base on the re-adjusted value of `currentSlide`:

```js
let currentSlide = 0
const holder = document.querySelector('.holder')
const totalSlides = holder.querySelectorAll('.holder-child')
const next = document.querySelector('.next')
const prev = document.querySelector('.prev')

const moveSlide = slide => {
  const leftPosition = -slide * 100 + 'vw'
  holder.style.left = leftPosition
}

const nextSlide = () => {
  currentSlide = currentSlide + 1
  if (currentSlide > totalSlides.length - 1) {
    currentSlide = 0
  }
  /* Final value for currentSlide now determined, so call moveSlide() 
     to position slides consistently with most up to date currentSlide
     value */
  moveSlide(currentSlide)
}

const prevSlide = () => {
  currentSlide = currentSlide - 1
  if (currentSlide < 0) {
    currentSlide = totalSlides.length - 1
  }
  /* Final value for currentSlide now determined, so call moveSlide() 
     to position slides consistently with most up to date currentSlide
     value */
  moveSlide(currentSlide)
}

next.addEventListener('click', () => {
  nextSlide()
})

prev.addEventListener('click', () => {
  prevSlide()
})
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.slideshow {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
}

.holder {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 500vw;
  transition: left 1s;
}

.holder-child {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
}

.speaker {
  padding: 0 8vw 0 8vw;
}

.controls {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<h2>Test</h2>
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="controls flex">
    <p class="prev pointer">prev</p>
    <p class="next pointer">next</p>
  </div>
  <div class=" holder flex">
    <div class="holder-child">
      <p>slide 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="holder-child">
      <p>slide 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```